# i am upload a video from s3 cloud front to an api with the help of ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, segmentation-fault, amazon-ecs

this is my api :
{
"title": "Dummy",
"url": "http://d2ia7k2fnq1u9w.cloudfront.net/Eagle-episode-12.mp4",
"category": "Cardio",
"exercises": 8,
"description": "This is a dummy video",
"tags": [
"google",
"blaze",
"hybrid",
"hbo"
]
}

and they give me this error :
{
"status": "error",
"message": "Command was killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): /home/ubuntu/gfwu-backend/node_modules/@ffprobe-installer/linux-x64/ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams [http://d2ia7k2fnq1u9w.cloudfront.net/Eagle-episode-12.mp4"](http://d2ia7k2fnq1u9w.cloudfront.net/Eagle-episode-12.mp4%22)
}

Answer (score 0):

That's segmentation fault (SIGSEGV). The error message you encountered shows that the command running ffprobe to analyze the video file was killed with a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

Meanwhile, if you try to ensure that the file and permission are goodwith the specified URL, and you are using updated version of FFmpeg and ffprobe.

Then, check if the EC2 instance is running out of resources (memory) during run time, you can consider upgrading the instance type or allocating more resources to it. A segmentation fault can occur if the process exhausts available memory.

Secondly, you need to confirm that the video in question is not corrupt. Try this code:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams Eagle-episode-12.mp4
```